# problem in sorting xml by date<xsl:sort select=""/>

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to sort my xml by date  but its not working my xml and xsl r like this

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="news/item">
                        <xsl:sort select="date1" order="descending" />                                     

                          <xsl:value-of select="date1"/>                                

                  </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>
```

MYXML

```
<news>
 <item>
<date1>January 1, 2010</date1>
 </item>
 <item>
  <date1>November 29, 2009</date1>
</news>


         Its displaying the result but not in sorted way..
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`xsl-sort`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_sort.asp) does not "know" how to sort dates. It will use default to text sort, though you can specify numeric sort by using the `data-type` attribute.

There are several approches to solve this - [add an attribute](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/sorting_dates_in_xsl.aspx) or change how you output the date to the source XML, so you have to a representation you can sort numerically.

Answer (score 6):

You can try to use something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/"> 
  <xsl:for-each select="news/item"> 
    <xsl:sort select="xs:date(date1)" order="descending" />
    <xsl:value-of select="date1"/>                                 
  </xsl:for-each>  
</xsl:template>
```

Although, if you have control over the XML generation, I'd also put something like:

```
<date1 isoValue="20100101">January 1, 2010</date1>
```

And then use

```
<xsl:sort select="xs:date(date1/@isoValue)" order="descending" />
```

Note the xs namespace below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Comment: what is the `xs` namespace?

Answer (score 2):

Check [this issue](https://adityabajaj.com/sort-x-ml-attribute-using-xslt/) for the problem's solution. It uses XSLT sort to sort XML by the dates in the XML.

Comment: @AdityaBajaj: From the comment to your edit, it seems that you have two accounts. You you should let them be merged into one: http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: @oberlies thanks for letting me know. I have submitted a merge request--have no idea how it was created.

Answer (score 1):

Date in the xml is a string. Unless the date always looks like this: yyyy-mm-dd you really can't sort it in the correct order.

So this is the correct way:

```
<xsl:sort select="newsDate"  order="ascending" />
```

It will works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

if you have control over the xml-generation:

Input:

```
<date1> 2010-10-17+02:00 </date1>
```

Transform:

```
<date1 number="{translate(substring-before(date1,'+'),'-','')}"
   <xsl:value-of select="date1"/>
</date1>`
```

Output:

```
<date1 number="20101017">2010-10-17+02:00</date1>
```

than you can use  like usual

```
<xsl:sort order="descending" select="@number" data-type="number"/>
```

Greetz

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the date1 field by using the US date format to create a year/month/date string, then sorting that descending.  In the xsl:for-each tag you would add this:

```
<xsl:sort select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@date1),1033,'yy/MM/dd')" order="descending" />
```