# How to Sort Dates in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a below XML structure and I want to sort the dates and update one date node to the latest date. Dates are in YYYY/mm/dd format. Below is the XML structure.

To be more specific I am putting an example below.
Let's say there are 3 Coverage Effective Dates 2015/01/01, 2015/01/02, 2015/01/03 then customerEffectiveDate should be updated to 2015/01/03.

Points to note about XML structure:
1. Product count can be from 1 to 10.
2. Coverage node can be from 1 to Many.

```
<Map>
    <customer>
        <customerDetails>
            <!-- The customerEffectiveDate below should be updated to the latest among all the effectiveDate fron coverage.-->
            <customerEffectiveDate>2014/06/02</customerEffectiveDate>
        </customerDetails>
    </customer>
    <products>
        <product1>
            <!-- Coverage Nodes can occur multiple times. There is no limit.-->
            <coverage>
                <effectiveDate>2015/12/01</effectiveDate>
            </coverage>
            <coverage>
                <effectiveDate>2015/11/01</effectiveDate>
            </coverage>
        </product1>
        <product2>
            <coverage>
                <effectiveDate>2014/12/01</effectiveDate>
            </coverage>
            <coverage>
                <effectiveDate>2015/09/01</effectiveDate>
            </coverage>
        </product2>
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .

        <product10></product10>
    </products>
</Map>
```

Another point to note is I am using XSL 1.0. Can someone please help.

I have already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094523/problem-in-sorting-xml-by-datexslsort-select), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421091/sorting-dates-in-xml-using-xslt) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688683/xslt-sort-date-and-number).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that format you can easily sort it, write a template

```
<xsl:template match="customer/customerDetails/customerEffectiveDate">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each select="//coverage/effectiveDate">
      <xsl:sort select="." data-type="text" order="descending"/>
      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

plus the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to copy the rest unchanged.

Comment: What does condition <xsl:if test="position() = 1"> would do? And what is "identity transformation template"?

Comment: I have edited the code to show how the identity transformation template looks like. As for the check, well, the code sorts in descending order and then takes the first value, the latest date, and outputs it.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most simple way, but this approach sorts all `<coverage>` tags under the `<product1-10>` tags, extracts the latest value from all `<effectiveDate>` values and copies the rest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Process <products> tag with higher priority, so that the follwing template does not match -->
<xsl:template match="products" priority="1">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(),'product')]">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
    <xsl:for-each select="coverage">
      <xsl:sort select="effectiveDate/text()" order="descending" />
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- extract the first 'effectiveDate' after sorting all values -->
<xsl:template match="customerEffectiveDate">
  <xsl:variable name="latest">
    <xsl:for-each select="../../../products//effectiveDate">
      <xsl:sort select="text()" order="descending" />
      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
  <customerEffectiveDate><xsl:copy-of select="$latest" /></customerEffectiveDate>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```